# num_rows no me detecta las filas en una consulta valida

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero validar si una consulta  recibe algún registro o no, y para eso estoy utilizando num_rows, pero me detecta siempre 0 filas. Pero pruebo a hacer la consulta, y me imprime datos.
Quiero detectar si recibe algun dato, por que si no quiero que luego haga un insert.

```
$sql = "SELECT  id_oferta,id_usuario FROM historial WHERE id_oferta = ? AND id_usuario = ?";

                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                 $stmt->bind_param('ii',$id_oferta,$id_usuario);
                 $stmt->execute();   
                 $stmt->bind_result($oferta,$usuario);
                 $stmt->fetch();

                 $row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows;

                 printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

             $stmt->close();
            $this->conn->close();
```

Comment: `num_rows` no es la mejor opción **para determinar si hay filas realmente**. Si el propósito es solamente ese, es mejor lanzar una consulta con `COUNT(*)`, y si aparte de eso te interesan también los datos que traería la consulta, entonces puedes verificar los mismos datos, en este caso, `$oferta` y/o `$usuario`

Comment: De acuerdo Cedano, comprobaré cómo hacerlo como dices, gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varia un poco usando sentencias preparadas: [mysqli_stmt::$num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

```
$stmt->execute();
// ...
$stmt->store_result();  
$row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso exactamente.